# Faster way to assign Unique ID to each group based on "DNA" of group

Tags: r

I have a problem where I need to group records based on characteristics of the group as a whole, but my current solution to do this is far too slow for the size of the datasets I'm working with.

Example dataset:

[image]

```
A   B   C
555 A1 K500
555 B2 H650
556 A1 K600
556 B2 H700
```

And so I need to make a new column that will give each group more information about that group, rather than just that in column A (eg 555).

Example output:

[image]

My current solution looks like the following, but takes far too long for the size of my dataset:

```
DNA <- function(x) {
Subset = filter(
    df,
    A==x)

Subset$Concat = paste(Subset$B,Subset$C,sep="")
toString(Subset$Concat)
}

df$DNA= mapply(DNA, df$A)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr`, something like:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
group_by(A) %>%
mutate(
D = paste(paste(B, C, sep = " "), collapse = " ")
)
```

In `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, D := paste(paste(B, C, sep = " "), collapse = " "), by = A]
```

Edit: I've rerun you example and have seen that you produce a column DNA that has a slightly different structure.

If you want to get such a column, you just replace the inner part in `dplyr` with `DNA = paste(paste0(B, C), collapse = ", ")`, and with `DNA := paste(paste0(B, C), collapse = ", ")` in `data.table`.

I've also run it through `microbenchmark`, since you said you're interested in speed (unit is milliseconds):

`DNA function`: 4.013901

`dplyr`: 1.664197

`data.table`: 0.7746959

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option

```
df1$D <- do.call(paste, df1[-1]) 
merge(df1[, -4], aggregate(D ~ A, df1, FUN = paste, collapse = " "), by = "A")
#    A  B    C               D
#1 555 A1 K500 A1 K500 B2 H650
#2 555 B2 H650 A1 K500 B2 H650
#3 556 A1 K600 A1 K600 B2 H700
#4 556 B2 H700 A1 K600 B2 H700
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(555L, 555L, 556L, 556L), B = c("A1", "B2", 
"A1", "B2"), C = c("K500", "H650", "K600", "H700")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```